# Import module components on demand

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, ecmascript-6, commonjs

I'm using a lib in my project and loading the components of it that I preset through the commonjs module system. The code looks like this:

```
let echart = require('echarts/lib/echarts');
require('echarts/lib/chart/scatter');
require('echarts/lib/component/title');
require('echarts/lib/component/toolbox');
require('echarts/lib/component/tooltip');
require('echarts/lib/component/legendScroll');
```

So the bundle generated by the webpack is 1.17 MB in size.

However, I decided to migrate the project to typescript and thus load the components of the lib through the import of es6. The code looks like this:

```
import * as echarts from 'echarts';
import ECharts = echarts.ECharts;
import EChartOption = echarts.EChartOption;
```

So the bundle generated by the webpack is 2.21 MB in size.
Because loading in this way all components are imported, even the ones I do not use.

Because of this inconvenience I would like to be able to do as in commonjs, someone knows if it is possible and how to do it?

Comment: `import {ECharts} from "echarts"`

Comment: wouldn't `import {Echarts, EchartOption} from 'echarts'` do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same deep nesting as in CommonJS:

```
import echarts = require('echarts/lib/echarts')
import 'echarts/lib/chart/scatter'
import 'echarts/lib/component/title'
import 'echarts/lib/component/toolbox'
import 'echarts/lib/component/tooltip'
import 'echarts/lib/component/legendScroll'
```

If you use `esModuleInterop` in TypeScript 2.7, you can do this for the first line:

```
import echarts from 'echarts/lib/echarts'
```